# How does AC analysis work on JFET circuits?

Tags: transistors

[image]

I have recently gotten into DC and AC part of JFET circuits, but I am stuck on this exercise. I need to do the DC analysis to find the Id and the voltages of figure. I also need to do an  AC analysis to find the Av (voltage amplification,) Ri (initial resistance,) Ro (the output resistsnce) as well as draw the equivalent circuit in AC and the shape of the final signal if the initial signal is 10 mV.

I have tried solving the DC part.

This is my attempt but I don't know if ive just made up things in my mind:

[image]

I apologize for my poor English as it is not my first language and I don't know the proper English terms.

Comment: Also you have to show your attempt to solve this, and exactly where you are stuck.  We can give hints and point you in the right direction, but we don't solve homework problems for you.

Comment: thank you for the editing advice in the comments this is my first time using Stackxhange i did not know how it works

Comment: @NoelCela - Hi,  The rules and etiquette on Stack Exchange are quite different from typical forums. Since you are new here, please read the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. There is also a (long) [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Thanks.